# Error thrown after ending the audio track / array of tracks in React Native Track Player

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I'm using React Native Track Player in a React Native project and playing an array of music tracks.
After ending the audio tracks, I'm getting the following error in the emulator:
(This error is thrown not only when I send an array but also even after playing an individual music file)

Error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double
> java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference.

[image]

As a solution what I tried to stop the player once the array of tracks is empty, but it is also.

```
useTrackPlayerEvents([Event.PlaybackQueueEnded], async event => {
  if (event.type === Event.PlaybackQueueEnded) {
    TrackPlayer.stop();
  }
});
```

Anybody who is familiar with `react-native-track-player`, can please help me to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code should be modified to check for undefined objects as follows (not **null objects**.)

```
useTrackPlayerEvents([Event.PlaybackQueueEnded], async event => {
  if (event.type === Event.PlaybackQueueEnded && event.nextTrack !== undefined) {
    TrackPlayer.stop();
  }
});
```