# Event 'PlaybackQueueEnded' is not fired in React Native Track Player

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I am using [react-native-track-player](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/docs/basics/installation) package to play music files in my React Native mobile application.

There due to some [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72122298/12215054), I need to stop the track-player once the queue of audio tracks reaches the end. For that, I use the event `PlaybackQueueEnded` to invoke the following code snippet. (I have used it in the `useTrackPlayerEvents` hook along with the `PlayerTrackChanged` event which when fired, sets the title, author, and background of the current audio file being played).

```
  useTrackPlayerEvents(
   
   // To set the title, author, and background of the current audio file being played

    [Event.PlaybackTrackChanged, Event.PlaybackQueueEnded],
    async event => {
      if (
        event.type === Event.PlaybackTrackChanged &&
        event.nextTrack !== null
      ) {
        const track = await TrackPlayer.getTrack(event.nextTrack);
        const title = track?.title;
        const artist = track?.artist;
        const artwork: SetStateAction<any> = track?.artwork;
        setTrackTitle(title);
        setTrackArtist(artist);
        setTrackArtwork(artwork);
      }

    // To stop the player once it reaches the end of the queue

      if (
        event.type === Event.PlaybackQueueEnded &&
        event.position === progress.duration
      ) {
        TrackPlayer.stop();
      }
    },
  );
```

But the above code doesn't work as I expected. Seems the event `PlaybackQueueEnded` is not fired when playing the last track of the queue. Can somebody please help me to solve this issue?

Thank you.

**PS:** I am taking the current time and duration of the audio file being played by using the `useProgress` hook and have assigned its value to the progress variable. By that, I'm taking `progress.position` and `progress.duration`.

Answer (score 0):

PlaybackQueueEnded will be fired when the song is finished and you dont need to check if event.position === progress.duration